# How can I stop a thread immediately if have multiple loops, without having multiple if else conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

**Now you may say, to stop a thread just use a global variable like this:**

```
stop_thread = False

for i in range(3):
    if stop_thread:
        break
    else:
        print(i)

    for j in range(10):
        if stop_thread:
            break
        else:
            print(j)
```

Now the problem with this approach is I need to add multiple if: else statements in each loop I have (to stop the thread immediately), I think If I'm working with a bigger code this approach may not be very readable or not organized. so what will be a better approach?

The condition is: if my code is running and it's inside somewhere in **'j'**, and suddenly stop_thread = True then should not complete the second loop or in short, the thread should be stopped immediately without using more resources.

Comment: If your loops are running in a function or method, you can break out of all of them at once by using `return` to return from the function/method.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner and for using return, I still need to use if-else.

Comment: What does "immediately" mean? Why is it a problem if the code finishes the current iteration of the loop before the thread stops? In the real code, is it *actually okay* for the thread to drop what it's doing immediately? What if it's, say, in the middle of sorting a list?

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions are handy for this because they let you break control flows across any number of levels (even across function calls).  For example:

```
try:
    for i in range(3):
        print(i)
        for j in range(10):
            if i * j > 5:
                raise StopIteration
            print("   ", j)
except StopIteration:
    print("Stopped!")
```

```
0
    0
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
1
    0
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
Stopped!
```

Put the `try/except` at whatever level you want control to return to when the exception is raised; no matter how deeply nested the scope that raises the exception is, the program's execution will jump directly to that `except`, interrupting everything in between.

Comment: The problem OP is talking about isn't simply with propagating the breakage in control flow; it's with responding "immediately" to the setting of a variable from an external context (another thread).

Comment: There's always: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-different-ways-to-kill-a-thread/